# add \figurename to \listoffigures (package titletoc)

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, titletoc

at the moment I'm a little bit fighting with my listoffigures. - I 'just' want to put the `\figurename`(here it is "Pict.") in front of the `\contentslabel` in the lof. Here's a little code example:

```
\documentclass[oneside,openright,BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=35mm, left=30mm, right=30mm, bottom=25mm, headsep=15mm, footskip=12mm}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{mparhack}

\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Pict.}}
\titlecontents{figure}[2.0cm]{\footnotesize}{\contentslabel{2.0cm}}{\hspace*{-1.5cm}}{\titlerule*[0.12cm]{.}\contentspage}[\addvspace{6pt}]

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}

\listoffigures

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=5cm]{demo}%
  \caption{My Picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

At the moment I tried this one:

```
\titlecontents{figure}[2.0cm]{\footnotesize}{\figurename\contentslabel{2.0cm}}{\hspace*{-1.5cm}}{\titlerule*[0.12cm]{.}\contentspage}[\addvspace{6pt}]
```

... but this always leads to something like:

```
"1.1 Pict.            My Picture ................................ 2"
```

But - as you might guess - that's not the thing I want. I want a result like:

```
"Pict. 1.1            My Picture with a long caption that has to
                      be broken ................................. 2"
```

Does anyone have a solution for me?
Thanks in advance,

eniem

Comment: This is typical for word, but think about it. Do you really need the word Pict for every item in a `list of figures`. I guess your readers are intelligent enough.

Comment: btw: using KOMA-script you can just use `listof=entryprefix`

Comment: @johannes_B you're right. but the problem is that my boss wants it that way and doesn't want to change ... :/

Answer (score 2):

Adding the same word to every single item in a list seems not the best way to be. Usually the types are given by the listname, for example `List of Tables` (Tabellenverzeichnis) or `List of Figures` (Abbildungsverzeichnis).

But if you really want to do that, you can use `listof=entryprefix`. I completely removed `titletoc` in my example, because it's use is not recommended with KOMA-classes.

```
\documentclass[listof=entryprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Pict.}}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Pict.}%also possible
%\usepackage{titletoc}
%\titlecontents{figure}[2.0cm]{\footnotesize}{\contentslabel{2.0cm}}{\hspace*{-1.5cm}}{\titlerule*[0.12cm]{.}\contentspage}[\addvspace{6pt}]
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \rule{4cm}{3cm}
  \caption{My Picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Loading yet *another* toc-altering package, you can achieve it in a much complexer way. Since i am a regular KOMA-user, i don't have much experience with `tocloft` nor `titletoc`. There might be better ways and i highly recommend using the tools \KOMAScript already gives you.

*I cannot recommend the following:*

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}%JB just to keep it on one page
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Pict.}
%the dance of the drunken sailor starts
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{figure}[\figurename 2.0cm]{\footnotesize}{\contentslabel{2.0cm}}{\hspace*{-1.5cm}}{\titlerule*[0.12cm]{.}\contentspage}[\addvspace{6pt}]
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlength\mylena
\settowidth\mylena{Figure}
\addtolength\cftfignumwidth{\mylena}
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{\figurename\space}
%The dance is over, but his ankles hurt. There might be something broken
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \rule{4cm}{3cm}
  \caption{My Picture}
  \caption{My Picture}
  \caption{My Picture}
  \caption{My Picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you ... but is there a possible solution with titletoc? (I use it for a lot of formatting, so it's a bit difficult to remove it 'cause then the layout doesn't work anymore :/ )

Comment: @eniem Please see my extended answer and the disclaimers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is 7 years old, but to not make future reader confused on the not working solution via `titletoc` (yes, KOMA-script is easier), All you need is to add `\hspace{-x}` before `\figurename`. That means :

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{figure}[3.0cm]%left section/margin
{}%abovecode, aka global formats usually
{\hspace{-2.2cm} \figurename  \ \thecontentslabel \}%numbered figure, in this case
{}%unnumbered figure, mostly unneeded for me
{\titlerule*[0.12cm]{.}\contentspage}%filler page, for the dotted lines
[\addvspace{6pt}] %vertspace, could be empty if you like it.
```

As you can see, the two important number to adjust is the number on left margin and the `\hspace` before figurename in numbered entry (and unnumbered, if you wish). For me 3 cm and -2.2cm is the answer, yours might differ.

My result would be

```
Figure 4.2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur elit
           Consectetur adipiscing elit ................ 42
```

and not

```
4.2 Figure Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur elit
           Consectetur adipiscing elit ................ 42
```

or

```
Figure 4.2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Consectetur elit
Consectetur adipiscing elit ........................... 42
```

It's not perfect (positioning is a mess, if you have a one-liner lof and two-liner they're not going to start at the same place i.e. the word `figure` doesn't actually start at the same place )