# List of Figures and List of Tables's format

Tags: table-of-contents

I have written my thesis in latex on sharelatex.

The problem is in the format of list of tables and figures.

My list of figures and tables are created as

1.1  Figure explanation...... Pg.Nmbr

But the thesis format must be like

Figure 1.1.   Figure explanation.....Pg.Nmbr

As far as I see in the style file, the section about list of tables and figures is this.

```
% Figures and Tables
%
\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand\figurename{Figure}
\renewcommand\tablename{Table}
%
% The spacing after the title of L.O.F. and L.O.T. is increased by
% one extra \baselineskip.
\renewcommand\listoffigures{% \ev is used for temporary strage of \parskip
\setlength{\ev}{\parskip}
\parskip0pt
    \chapter*{\listfigurename
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}%
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \@starttoc{lof}%
\parskip\ev}
%
\renewcommand\listoftables{% \ev is used for temporary storage of \parskip
\setlength{\ev}{\parskip}
\parskip0pt
    \chapter*{\listtablename
      \@mkboth{%
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}%
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \@starttoc{lot}%
\parskip\ev}
%
% The expressions 'FIGURE' and 'TABLE' also appear in the LOF and LOT.
% Also there is a period after the figure or table number.
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{\par\addcontentsline{\csname
  ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}
% The \csname command should follow immediately after {
  {\protect\numberline{\csname #1name\endcsname \space
  \csname the#1\endcsname .}{\ignorespaces #2}\vspace\baselineskip}\begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
%
% The space between the figure and caption is reduced from 10\p@ to 0\p@
% The value of \belowcaptionskip (0\p@) has not been changed.
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0\p@}
%
% A period should appear after the caption number.
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \centering{
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1. #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1. #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  } % closes centering
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
%
% The spaces between the figure or table number and the caption are
% redefined.
\renewcommand\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{6em}}
\renewcommand\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{5.8em}}
%
```

And I put my figures into the text like this :

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/strainmeters_all.png}
\caption{Measuring Techniques of Borehole Strainmeter Types (modified from Ishii et al, 2015).}
\vskip\baselineskip % Leave a vertical skip below the figure
\label{fig:strainmeasure_all}
\end{figure}
```

How can I fix this code to get the result as I want ?

[image: My list]

[image: Desired list]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  you can format your code by highlighting it with the mouse and then clicking on the `{}` icon that appears above the question box.  for single code lines, start the line with four spaces.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of showing us a fragment of code from a class without telling us what class it is, make a small compilable document that uses it that shows your problem.

Comment: There should be similar questions already here.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183060/add-figurename-to-listoffigures-package-titletoc for example.  Note that you have complete control using \l@figures.